# Regex expression to clean up invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have to use an API which returns invalid JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "tags": [
                {
                    "t": "DefaultKPI",
                    d: "Some default KPI parameters",
                    cv: 6.0000000000000000,
                    cvS: "6.000",
                    ct: 0,
                    tv: "",
                    tvS: "NaN",
                    u: "",
                    s: 0,
                    gmax: "",
                    gmaxS: "NaN",
                    gmin: "",
                    gminS: "NaN",
                    hhh: "",
                    hhhS: "NaN",
                    hh: "",
                    hhS: "NaN",
                    h: "",
                    hS: "NaN",
                    l: "",
                    lS: "NaN",
                    ll: "",
                    llS: "NaN",
                    lll: "",
                    lllS: "NaN",
                    up: ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the names are not always surrounded by quotes.
I would like to create a JS function to add them, which mean selecting them to check if there is quotes, and if not, add them.

I am new to regex, so I have been trying things on regex101 for a while, but I have trouble figuring it out.

What I have so far is

```
/(,.*?:)/
```

It matches to

```
,d:
```

I understood from tutorials that

```
/(,.*?:)+/
```

would select them all, but it does not work.

Moreover, I would like to remove the delimiters from the match (for example, my previous example should return

```
d
```

It would make my life much easier in the replacement part, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to fix the cause instead of the symptom? Especially since "fixing" that is not that easy... It definitely cannot be done based on a regular expression, since you need a stateful machine for this. You probably can find something that works in most cases, but this approach will never result in a robust solution.

Comment: This is pure luck.
Some more complex responses just have one quote, on one side or the other...

Therefore I really need to validate the strings before parsing

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. I agree with @arkascha. Your API is not actually giving "non-standard" JSON, it's giving you JSON that doesn't parse. And that data is useless. Fix it on the server.

Comment: @arkascha, I agree with you, I have told the API devs about this, but it might be quite a while before they fix it, and I would have hoped to get it to work more quickly...

Comment: Sure, well known situation, but as said: not really possible without _huge_ effort. All you could find is a dirty hack.

Comment: Or, until they fix it, just use a temporary data set that works.

Answer (score 0):

If it parses as JS (and this does), then hold your nose and use `eval`. When your code fails review, tell your boss you'll get rid of `eval` the minute the server guys stand up and give you proper JSON.

Remember you'll have to surround it in parentheses, or add `var foo =` at the beginning, so JS doesn't get confused and think the leading `{` starts a block.

Now hope and pray the server wizards don't figure out a way to give you something which is so broken in some other way that even `eval` can't handle it.